# blocked threads on a jsf app running on glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf, glassfish, jsf-2.2

I have a JSF 2.2 spring 4.x running on a glassfish 4.1.1 server.
The server is proxyed by an apache 2.4 which sends all the requests to glassfish via ajp protocol.
The AJP listener is mapped on a thread pool with min 50 and max 150 threads.
Lately I have notices that when the number of users logged in app reaches ~100 or more the app is slow respondind although the load is not big on app server or database server.
Running visualVM on that server I have noticed a lot of 150 ajp threads are most of the time blocked with something like:

```
"ajp-listener(89)" - Thread t@3357
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:404)
- waiting to lock <7c1a25e8> (a org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader) owned by "ajp-listener(26)" t@237
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1730)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.ObjectFactory.findProviderClass(ObjectFactory.java:209)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.ObjectFactory.newInstance(ObjectFactory.java:157)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.ObjectFactory.newInstance(ObjectFactory.java:143)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory.getInstance(DTDDVFactory.java:64)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory.getInstance(DTDDVFactory.java:49)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.<init>(XML11Configuration.java:578)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.<init>(XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.java:130)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.<init>(XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.java:91)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(SAXParser.java:111)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(SAXParser.java:96)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(SAXParserImpl.java:412)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(SAXParserImpl.java:136)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.createSAXParser(SAXCompiler.java:524)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:453)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:430)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:481)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$NoCache.get(DefaultFaceletCache.java:243)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$NoCache.get(DefaultFaceletCache.java:236)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:124)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:63)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:295)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:370)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:124)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:585)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:151)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.restoreView(FlowViewHandler.java:84)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.restoreView(FlowViewHandler.java:84)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.restoreView(FlowViewHandler.java:84)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:133)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

Any idea of what can cause that ?

PS. I have found on the internet a similar topic and there the problem was with the  javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE that was not set to production but in this case it is.

Update:
I have updated Mojara from 2.2.12 to 2.2.13 and I still see a lot of blocked threads but it seems the app is moving better than with 2.2.12.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
In this case the issue was that in production system javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD was set to 0. Update this to 900 seconds fixed the issue. So it becomes

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>900</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: That is weird... A refresh period of 0 should not block threads, although, it might be that you think they are stuck but just the disk-io is relatively expensive. Do disable you can set it to -1 btw...

Comment: The majority of threads were colored red in visualVM. ( "ajp-listener(89)" - Thread t@3357
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:404)
- waiting to lock <7c1a25e8> (a org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader) owned by ... )                  I do not want to disable permanently as there were cases where I need to make some html updates in production without redeploying the app.